# CSS not loading until cursor hover

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css, inertiajs

So lets start off with a little video first.

https://www.loom.com/share/a1dd16e7c77241bfbf0ef32980c1c8e9

In this video, you will see when I open up the dropdown menu on the top right corner, the menu is missing all of the Tailwind Classes. I have no idea why this is occurring but the moment I hover over it they load and persist.

Any idea why this might be happening. Happy to show code just not sure what would even be causing it.

Comment: Probably better that you dispense with the video and instead do the expected thing and add the minimal code required to reproduce your problem. A video of the results sounds to me like an image of text - not exactly awesome. Code on the other hand that displays the error may well garner you an explanation that allows you to avoid the problem in the future. ;)

Comment: Truly I struggled with what code snippet to provide its why I went with the video and tried to tag the technologies being used. In the end the solution was upgrading tailwind to 2.2

Comment: I understand the difficulty of posing a question in the suggested format, really I do. Please don't interpret my previous comment as hostile (I've no indication that you did) - so many times, one can solve their own quandary during the process of condensing the code down to the smallest required to reproduce the problem. It seems here, that someone's advice is *perfect* - "By adding and using Tailwind, we’re introducing a layer of complexity to our project. And layers introduce risk. Things can go wrong. And they will" (like they did for you!)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have the answer but I do not like it. When I upgraded my app with npm update, the problem went away. I do not know why, I wish I did so I could document it for further concerns but it doesnt exist anymore.